# Connect C# to Hive using cloudera ODBC driver

Tags: c#, hive, odbc, cloudera

Can you please help me to connect my C# application with hive database using Cloudera ODBC driver. We are using Kerberos authentication. I am using this connection string:

```
 conn = new OdbcConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = @"DRIVER={Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive};                                        
                                    Host=host_name;
                                    Port=10000;
                                    Schema=default;
                                    HiveServerType=2;
                                    AuthMech=1;
                                    KrbRealm=realm_name;
                                    KrbHostFQDN=FQDN_name;
                                    KrbServiceName=hive;
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
```

I have been able to setup the User DSN and the Test was successful. I have also tested by just passing the DSN name in the connection string bust still am getting the same error message.

Please help me if you have any solution to this!